# Database connectivity in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

The Scrapy documentation does a fine job explaining how to connect to a database in it's [MongoDB Pipeline Example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb).

If I write another pipeline that also needs database access, I'll need to create another connection.  If I write a Downloader Middleware (to log requests in a database), that's another.  Database connections are rather expensive, and this feels fairly wasteful.  SQL Alchemy, for example uses a connection pool for this.

To my question(s): is there a better way to establish the connection and re-use it across Extensions, Middlewares, and Pipelines? Are there any issues with the asynchronous nature of Scrapy and the default DBAPI2 (namely: and would it be better/useless to look into using `twisted.enterprise.adbapi`)?

I've considered an extension with something similar to the following (assume proper function calls via signals):

```
import MySQLdb

def __init__(self):
    self.db = MySQLdb.connect('...')

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    spider.db = self.db

def spider_closer(self, spider):
    spider.db.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have this exact same question. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your shared code in an arbitrary module, à la singleton, and call that code from any of your item pipelines, downloader middlewares, spider middlewares or extensions.

As for `twisted.enterprise.adbapi`, it would definitely be better if you feel up to the task, in order to prevent your database connections from blocking your crawls.